# Propositional Logic involving double "not" P if and only if Not(NOT P)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm attempting to prove

[enter link description here](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/c90f7112eff916f026ad22d62f8b09694c83504e)

I can only use prepositional logic. I tried to use the not+/- rules but they require me to assume P and not P at the same time. I'm genuinely lost at this point

Comment: What are the axioms you are working with? Have you proved any other theorems yet?

Comment: Add some explanation of the link's content is preferred.

Comment: I can only use Gentzen's ten rules of propositional logic